# Spring boot server client request with timeout

Tags: spring-boot, rest, websocket

I've been developing online ordering application that a customer order using his/her mobile application and the service provider got the order in realtime but the challenge is that I want the order to be cancelled if the service provider didn't accept the order within a specified time span. How to make it happen using spring boot technologies?

[image]

this is the architecture of the system I'm trying to achieve plus the request is synchronous

Comment: The question is too broad, can you please put your current design here ? Is all of this sync or async ? communication happens over HTTP or MQ or some other protocol ? A lot of specific details might be required to possibly give an answer that helps you.

Comment: @AmarDev I just update my question. I think it's a bit clear now, right?